# How do i write objects that i have no control over in jaxb?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am trying to find a way to marshall classes that i have no access to. I am trying to achieve something like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="bar")
class Bar {
  @XmlAttribute
  private Foo foo;

  @XmlAttribute
  private String baz;
}
```

which should result in a xml file like this:

```
<bar baz="stuff" foo="otherstuff"/>
```

Is this possible? I tried to fiddle with `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` with no sucess.

Comment: You have access to the Bar source, but not Foo?

Comment: You could use the external mapping document in EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy):  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/09/mapping-objects-to-multiple-xml-schemas.html

Comment: @KyleMahan Bar source yes, Foo Source no ... exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with XmlJavaTypeAdapter, but I suspect foo needs to be an XmlElement rather than an XmlAttribute:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="bar")
public class Bar {

  @XmlElement
  @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(FooAdapter.class)
  private Foo foo;

  @XmlAttribute
  private String baz;

}
```

FooAdapter can be as simple as the following, but the output will be prettier if you make a proxy object to represent Foo and marshal that rather than Object[].

```
class FooAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Object[], Foo> {

    @Override
    public Object[] marshal(Foo v) throws Exception {
        return new Object[]{ v.x, v.y, v.z };
    }

    @Override
    public Foo unmarshal(Object[] v) throws Exception {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.x = (String) v[0];
        foo.y = (Integer) v[1];
        foo.z = (Double) v[2];
        return foo;
    }

}
```

Comment: yep that works just perfect ... actually it even works with `@XmlAttribute` if you create a `XmlAdapter<String, Foo>`. Would there be a way to get away without using the Bar class? `Marshaller` has a `setAdapter` function that takes an `XmlAdapter` ... but registering `FooAdapter` and marshalling `Foo` alone doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have access to the classes used to generate an XML file, but you do have access to the schema based on/used to generate those classes, you should be able to re-generate those classes using xjc and the schema definition (xsd) file.

Comment: hmm... guess i wasn't clear enough ... there is no xml schema ... everything is Annotion based. It boils down to the question: "how do i teach JAXB about new classes when i have no access to these classes?"